# Multiple joins with aggregation - DB independent

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I've looked through many topics, still I can't find my way out of it.

I have three models. A, B and C iheriting after ActiveRecord::Base.

```
A
  belongs_to :b
  parts:integer

B
  belongs_to :c
C
  name:string
```

What I want to get is sum of parts from A grouped by C.name but totally independently from the database to receive such result:

```
{ 
  name1 => sumOfParts1,
  name2 => sumOFParts2,
  ...
}
```

What I have got now is:

```
@results = @as.joins(:b).group('bs.c_id').sum(:parts)
```

what looks like this

```
{ 
  1 => sumOfParts1,
  2 => sumOFParts2,
  ...
}
```

I'm new to Rails but I want to do it as clean as it can be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this:

`@results = @as.joins(:b => :c).group('cs.name').sum(:parts)`

Or try to add to A:

`has_one :c, through: b`

And then you can do:

`@results = @as.joins(:c).group('cs.name').sum(:parts)`

Comment: my guess is that c.name is supposed to be unique... it would probably be cleaner to go from the other direction with c.as

Comment: In case of cs.name uniqueness (like @user3334690 said) you should group by 2 fields: `group('cs.id, cs.name')`

Comment: And what is the reason for that kind of grouping?

Comment: If you have several `cs` records with the same `name` field (but with different ids), `group(:name)` merge all same `name` into one field.